# windows php exec apache

Tags: php, windows, apache, exec

windows 10, php 5.6 as mod, apache 2 service

in browser i dont see that exec() return any value

```
<?php
exec("python c:\script.py", $output);
var_dump($output);
```

if i change the command from using "python" to smth like "dir" it works good and return results

```
<?php
exec("dir", $output);
var_dump($output);
```

if i run python script from the command line it works good as expected

```
> python c:\script.py
```

if i run php script from the command line it works good as expected and exec return required results from the python script

```
> php -r "exec('python c:\script.py', $output); var_dump($output);"
```

i suppose this problem related to the apache permissions or php permissions to python.exe ? may be smth. else ?

advise me pls and explain how to change permissions im not familiar with windows it is not user friendly :D kidding :)

Comment: is python.exe in the path of the user that apache's executing that line as? you may need `exec('"c:/program files/python/blah/blah/python.exe" foo.python');` instead.

Comment: python.exe added to the PATH so this shouldnt be an issue, but i just tried and it didnt help.
i have also added permissions to the "python.exe" and "script.py":
LOCAL SERVICE - All permissions
NETWORK SERVICE - All permissions
All - All permissions
these permissions didnt help as well, exec do not return any values if i run php script through the browser

Comment: what about exit status? try the 3rd arg for exec() and see what value you get back from the shell.

Comment: exec($cliCommand, $output, $status);
var_dump($output);
var_dump($status);

result: array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }   int(0)

Comment: well, start digging deeper. have this python script write to a file, or a log, or whatever, see if it's even being executed under the "non-working" php call.

Comment: what do you mean by the non working php call ? 
if i run script from the command line like this (as administrator):
>php -r "exec('python c:\script.py', $a); var_dump($a);"

i have result: 
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(60) "ablt:blabla;gent:blabla;datv:blabla;accs:blabla;loct:blabla;"
}

Comment: "I don't see return any value". THAT version. you get a 0 exit code, which indicates something succeeded, so check what in the script isn't working when you run in that way.

Comment: php script as simple as shown in description - just 2 lines.
python script also works well as we can see in case i run php script from the command line.
exec() supposed to run "python c:\script.py" in cmd.exe like i do it manually from the command line and return results ? probably no permissions to cmd.exe ?

Comment: if i run from the command line: > php script.php it also do not return any results, may be this give some additional ideas about the problem to some one

Comment: exec only returns stdout output as well. if your python script is writing to stderr, php will ignore that.

Comment: but why it works well if i run script directly through > php -r "blabla"

Comment: because stderr goes to the screen as well, but won't be captured by php to return back to the php code. runninga t the command line and via exec are two totally different environments. your shell isa  terminal, it has flow control, it has cursors, colors, blah blah blah. running through `exec()` has no terminal at all.

Comment: ok, great so how to transfer from the stderr to the stdout in windows ?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/110930

Comment: python script uses print(lex.line()) i dont think it send results to stderr...  according to the docs above from stderr i can redirect data to the file like 2>aa.txt , so i tried exec('python c:\script.py 2>aa.txt', $output) ... aa.txt empty i gave up :'(  on ubuntu everything works well but this windows blows my mind :(  i tried and this really works and redirect from stderr to the file: > blabla 2>xx.txt and i got in txt file message that "blabla" not recognized and so on

Comment: additionally tried: > python script.py >aa.txt it return data to stdout not to stderr, so problem not in stdout or stderr i suppose, problem in smth else